# Navigation, background swap not having every <li> on mouseover

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am using the following jquery code:

```
$("#top ul li.corner").mouseover(function(){
    $("span.left-corner").addClass("left-corner-hover");
    $("span.right-corner").addClass("right-corner-hover");
    $("span.content").addClass("content-hover");
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("span.left-corner").removeClass("left-corner-hover");
    $("span.right-corner").removeClass("right-corner-hover");
    $("span.content").removeClass("content-hover");

});
```

But as you see in the selector that is going to do every li.corner that the mouse is over. i am trying to get it to do only the one the mouse is over, how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to approximate what i imagined your code would look like, and the test runs fine:

css:

```
.left-corner-hover, .right-corner-hover, .content-hover {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#top ul li.corner").mouseover(function(){
    $("span.left-corner", this).addClass("left-corner-hover");
    $("span.right-corner", this).addClass("right-corner-hover");
    $("span.content", this).addClass("content-hover");
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("span.left-corner", this).removeClass("left-corner-hover");
    $("span.right-corner", this).removeClass("right-corner-hover");
    $("span.content", this).removeClass("content-hover");

});
```

html:

```
<div id="top">
    <ul>
        <li class="corner">
            <span class="left-corner">Left Corner</span>
            <span class="content">Content</span>
            <span class="right-corner">Right Corner</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="corner">
            <span class="left-corner">Left Corner</span>
            <span class="content">Content</span>
            <span class="right-corner">Right Corner</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are your `<span>` elements within your `<li>`? if so you could do something like:

```
$('#top ul li.corner').mouseover(function() {
    $('span.left-corner', this).addClass('left-corner-hover');
    // etc...
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('span.left-corner', this).removeClass('left-corner-hover');
    // etc...
});
```

basically, this would assign/remove the classes to the specific `<span>` elements within the `<li>` called.

depending on how much stuff is in there, you may get better results using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, to avoid triggering mouseover when you cross element boundaries:

```
$('#top ul li.corner').bind('mouseenter', function() {
  // etc...
}).bind('mouseleave', function() {
  // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#top ul li.corner").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find(".left-corner").addClass("left-corner-hover");
    // ...
});
```

You probably don't need to specify that it's a 'span' element.

Another thing to try is to just add and remove the 'hover' class, and have your CSS rules look like:

```
.left-corner.hover { ... }
.right-corner.hover { ... }
```